# Consequences of Littlewood-Richardson rule

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

I am trying to read [Deligne's paper 'Categories Tensorielles'](https://www.math.ias.edu/files/deligne/Tensorielles.pdf), and in the first chapter Deligne states some results obtained from the Littlewood-Richardson rule that I do not understand.

He states: 'Fix $r$ and a partition $\lambda$ of $n$. For there to exist $n_1,\dots,n_r$ of sum $n$ such that $[\lambda: (n_1),\dots,(n_r)] \neq 0$, it is necessary and sufficient that $[\lambda]$ has at most $r$ rows.'

Here the notation $[\lambda: (n_1),\dots,(n_r)]$ means the multiplicity of $V_{\lambda}$ in $\otimes _i V_{(n_i)}$. Can someone explain how he gets this result?

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the Pieri Rule https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/schur.htm#schurPieriRule

Comment: "au plus" = "at most", not "at least".

Comment: @darijgrinberg I do not speak any French so I used a translation. Thank you for noticing, I would have never found out!

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @S.Farr: Did you read the statement of Pieri's rule  I referred to? You just have to apply it successively as you tensor with a new $V_{(n_i)}$. Watch out for the length of the first column and keep in mind what the rule says about not putting two new boxes in the same column. In any case, this is not research level and thus not suitable for MO. It should be asked on math.stackexchange instead

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd: this might be your translation; in that case it would probably not hurt to fix the "at least". Thank you!